# Amazon AWS hadoop- how to download a file from s3 in map-reduce program in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce

I am trying to make a quite simple map-reduce program that as part of the map task it needs to load a small file from S3 (something that can be saved in the local memory).

In the map reduce the task is to check each line against this file and generate a feature vector (and so on...)

I am having troubles with making my setup method downloading and accessing this file.
I think the problem is with forwarding the credentials but it might as well be in the way I am accessing the file in the setup function (I put code snippets below).

In my map-reduce logs the error I'm getting is:
"profile file cannot be null"
about this line:

```
            AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials());
```

I tried many other ways and got nowhere, if there is anyway you can guide me it will be great.

In my main (running local on my pc) java file I do:

```
AmazonElasticMapReduce mapReduce =AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").build();
HadoopJarStepConfig hadoopJarStep = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("MYPATH")  // This should be a full map reduce application.
                .withMainClass("MYMAIN");
```

in the mapreduce jar (the one that runs on the ec2 task) I define the relevant jobs and the job contorl, and in the setup function of the map class I do:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials());
            AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
                    .withRegion("us-east-1")
                    .build();
            String S3Bucket = "MYBUCKET";  // the bucket where the file is located
            String S3Key = "MYKEY"; // the name of the file
            S3Object object = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(S3Bucket, S3Key)); // bucket, key
            S3ObjectInputStream summaryInputStream = object.getObjectContent();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(summaryInputStream));
```

I also tried to hard code my credentials in the main (run local on my pc) like this:

```
String access_key = "aws_access_key_id=MYKEY";
        String secret_key = "aws_secret_access_key=MYSECRETKEY";

        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key, secret_key);
        AWSStaticCredentialsProvider awsCred = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds);
        AmazonElasticMapReduce mapReduce =
                AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1").withCredentials(awsCred).build();
```

also with no success (I tried with excluding the "aws_access_key_id=" and the "aws_secret_access_key=" from the strings)

Thanks!

Comment: whats the error that you are getting?

Comment: I edited ths post with the error.